# Inserting Two values using MYSQL into a combobox.item.add

Tags: c#, mysql, database

So I was trying to add the firstName and lastName in my combobox in my voting system project for our school. I'm getting an error which is getString is not possible to use in this type of syntax. Is there any other way to add this values into 1 single slot to my combo box?

```
 using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection))
            {
                //Opening of Connection
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dataReader;

                //FOR PRESIDENT
                using (MySqlCommand votePresident = new MySqlCommand(displayPresident, con))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        int votePres = 0;
                        votePres = votePresident.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dataReader = votePresident.ExecuteReader();
                    //Loop to read the Data
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        String rollPres = dataReader.GetString("firstName","lastName");
                        presidentbox.Items.Add(rollPres);
                    }

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to Vote" + ex);
                    }

                }
```

[Error Shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk7JE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved while searching the internet
I used this to connect the 2 strings

```
while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        String rollPresf = dataReader.GetString("firstName");
                        String rollPresl = dataReader.GetString("lastName");
                        presidentbox.Items.Add(rollPresf + " " + rollPresl);
                    }
```